# VBA Word: How to separate content from formatting information?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a VBA-macro that converts a given MS word document into a sequential list of the document objects contained in that document (e.g., Paragraph, Table, etc.). For each of those objects I want to extract the text contained and its explicit formatting information to save it in a DB.

Would have any pointers for me how to get started? Are there any elegant solutions to this document parsing task?

Comment: hi pat, what are you trying to achieve with this, there are some solutions available for this already that might help you.

Comment: Hi, Toby - I am trying to improve a presently very manual documentation localisation process (conversion of documents between languages).

Comment: My approach would be to step through the ordered list of objects in the doc, retrieving the object type and then having subroutines for the specific handling of each object type such as tables and images.

Comment: you are asking 'how to get started' while I see you know the way you should go... you just need few `for each` loops plus implementation of your logic and that's it.

Comment: Thanks, KazJaw. My problem is that I don't know which array or enumeration to iterate over. Any insights on that? I would need an ordered data structure that contains all of the doc's content objects.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your full requirements this is just some suggestions.

You may be able to do what you want, but it will be a mammoth task to pull apart word documents and be able to stich them back together.  If you di dwant to go with this approach, the best might be to pull out paragraphs, images etc and save these sections as individual documents in your database.  They can then be put back together using

```
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

 MsgBox ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Item(i)


Next i


ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter AnotherDocument
```

This is incredibly basic and will be a LOT of work to get working correctly.

I wonder would turning the documents into html be better (done simply by saving as HTML) and then you can use open source libraries to allow users to edit parts of the document.  Eg add the [jeditable](http://plugins.jquery.com/jeditable/) plugin for jquery and almost any paragraph in your html word document becomes editable.  A simple backend php script to save the changes and you have something that works.  You can then also note what has changed for translation purposes.

They docs can be saved back as word docs or pdfs before being sent to the customer

Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks, Tobi. I have used the HTML-based work-around in combination with a Perl-script when trying to extract reliably tokens in a specific format (a VBA-script to do the same kept failing). My main concerns are two-fold: 1) HTML only approximates the full scope of available formats. 2) Complex documents will have an equally complex mark-up (which, I fear may be less accessible than clear VBA-scripting).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer to jeditable. I will follow up on that.

Comment: The comment regarding the object-based VBA-approach does not sound very encouraging. Why would that be so hard? Isn't there a single enumeration available that one could iterate over to get all objects in the doc? My view is that paragraphs are probably way to large for the task at hand. I want to capture every formatting info on every word in the doc!

Comment: I think if there was a single iteration you would know it already.  Word HTML does an extraordinary job of being able to replicate almost all word features.  Try pulling our every word and see what happens. If in doubt record a macro when you do something and see what code word generates in VBA.